# read text from file and use in if statement

Tags: python

I have a file with the following contents

```
Name = John

Last Name = Doe

Gender = Male

Date of Birth = 01-Jul-1990

Place of Brith = New York
```

and the following function for the file

```
def find_regex_1(k, s):
    reg = f'{k}\s*=\s*(\S+)'
    return re.search(reg, s).group(1)

def read_configs(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        name = find_regex_1('Name', content)
        last_name = find_regex_1('Last Name', content)
        gender = find_regex_1('Gender', content)
        birth_date = find_regex_1('Date of Birth', content)
        birth_place = find_regex_1('Place of Brith', content)
    return name, last_name, gender, birth_date, birth_place

name, last_name, gender, birth_date, birth_place = read_configs('form.txt')
```

Now I want to make an `if statement` for the `Gender` like if is `Male` do something and if is `Female` Do something else but I don't know how to call the functions above to use the content of `Gender` as verifying it and use in if statement

what I'm already doing and satisfied with is to use the content of gender by calling `gender` and reads the content but what I want now is to read the content and recognize the value for using in if statement

Comment: Your  ```return``` statement should be inside the function

Comment: it is just pasted wrong here sorry fixed

Comment: Where do you want to use those `if`? In principle you would just do `if gender == 'Male:` or `if gender == 'Female':`

Comment: No problem. Looking at your code, I don't think you need regex for getting the gender. You can split the string on the ```=``` and then use ```your_var[1].strip().lower()=='male```:```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the if-statement after your with-statement:

```py
def read_configs(config_file):
    with open(config_file, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
        name = find_regex_1('Name', content)
        last_name = find_regex_1('Last Name', content)
        gender = find_regex_1('Gender', content)
        birth_date = find_regex_1('Date of Birth', content)
        birth_place = find_regex_1('Place of Brith', content)

    if gender == 'Male':
        # Do something
        pass
    elif gender == 'Female':
        # Do something
        pass

    return name, last_name, gender, birth_date, birth_place
```

Comment: I want to use it anywhere in the code so I can use it like if `gender == 'Male':` anywhere I want?

Comment: No @CatChMeIfUCan, only after ```gender``` is assigned

Comment: I know that! I meant after that function!

Comment: You can use it after `name, last_name, gender, birth_date, birth_place = read_configs('form.txt')` if that is what you need, since you already have `gender` defined.

Comment: yea so no need for regex reading before I place the if statement?

Comment: No, because you already did that in your function...